# Python 3 string to hex

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, hex

In Python 2 these all worked:

```
>>> "hello".encode("hex")
'68656c6c6f'
>>> b"hello".encode("hex")
'68656c6c6f'
>>> u"hello".encode("hex")
'68656c6c6f'
```

But in Python 3:

```
>>> "hello".encode("hex")
LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs
```

How to convert string to hex in Python 3?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The `hex` codec has been chucked in 3.x. Use [`binascii`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex) instead:

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'hello')
b'68656c6c6f'
```

Comment: BTW, binary codes made a comeback in version 3.2, [see docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#binary-transforms)

Comment: What if my string is stored in a variable?

Comment: That gives an error, because the argument has to be a bytes-like object.

Comment: To convert a String to binary sequence you can use ".encode()". Example: "This is your String".encode()

Comment: Why is this better than e.g. `b'hello'.hex()`?

Comment: What was the point of breaking backward compatibility like that? I don't understand the mindset.

Answer (score 55):

In Python 3.5+, encode the string to bytes and use the `hex()` method, returning a string.

```
s = "hello".encode("utf-8").hex()
s
# '68656c6c6f'
```

Optionally convert the string back to bytes:

```
b = bytes(s, "utf-8")
b
# b'68656c6c6f'
```

Comment: This the way to do it for a Python 3 string variable. Lot of the answers here are regarding constants. A practical code is rarely that.

Comment: Emphasis on >=Python 3.5 if you want to use `hex()`

Answer (score 26):

You've already got some good answers, but I thought you might be interested in a bit of the background too.

Firstly you're missing the quotes. It should be:

```
"hello".encode("hex")
```

Secondly this codec hasn't been ported to Python 3.1. See [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue7475). It seems that they haven't yet decided whether or not these codecs should be included in Python 3 or implemented in a different way.

If you look at the [diff file](http://bugs.python.org/file15526/issue7475_missing_codecs_py3k.diff) attached to that bug you can see the proposed method of implementing it:

```
import binascii
output = binascii.b2a_hex(input)
```

Answer (score 26):

**The easiest way to do it in Python 3.5 and higher is:**

```
>>> 'halo'.encode().hex()
'68616c6f'
```

**If you manually enter a string into a Python Interpreter** using the `utf-8` characters, you can do it even faster by typing `b` before the string:

```
>>> b'halo'.hex()
'68616c6f'
```

**Equivalent in Python 2.x:**

```
>>> 'halo'.encode('hex')
'68616c6f'
```

Comment: Thank you @ner0 for your important comment!

Comment: No worries. If v3.4 or below is a requirement, this will do: `from binascii import hexlify
str(hexlify(bytes('halo', encoding = 'utf-8')), 'ascii')`

Comment: Is this because `.hex()` wasn't added until Python 3.5? A link to the changelog would have been really good in this answer as context :-)

Answer (score 24):

binascii methodes are easier by the way

```
>>> import binascii
>>> x=b'test'
>>> x=binascii.hexlify(x)
>>> x
b'74657374'
>>> y=str(x,'ascii')
>>> y
'74657374'
>>> x=binascii.unhexlify(x)
>>> x
b'test'
>>> y=str(x,'ascii')
>>> y
'test'
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: binascii is also faster than the other methods. Just tested with timeit.

Comment: How do you do string to hex conversion, if the string is a regular Python 3 string, not binary or a constant?

Answer (score 10):

In Python 3, all strings are unicode. Usually, if you encode an unicode object to a string, you use `.encode('TEXT_ENCODING')`, since `hex` is not a text encoding, you should use `codecs.encode()` to handle arbitrary codecs. For example:

```
>>>> "hello".encode('hex')
LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs
>>>> import codecs
>>>> codecs.encode(b"hello", 'hex')
b'68656c6c6f'
```

Again, since "hello" is unicode, you need to indicate it as a byte string before encoding to hexadecimal. This may be more inline with what your original approach of using the `encode` method.

The differences between **`binascii.hexlify`** and **`codecs.encode`** are as follow:

- **binascii.hexlify**

  Hexadecimal representation of binary data.

  The return value is a bytes object.

  Type:      builtin_function_or_method
- **codecs.encode**

  encode(obj, [encoding[,errors]]) -> object

  Encodes obj using the codec registered for encoding. encoding defaults
  to the default encoding. errors may be given to set a different error
  handling scheme. Default is 'strict' meaning that encoding errors raise
  a ValueError. Other possible values are 'ignore', 'replace' and
  'xmlcharrefreplace' as well as any other name registered with
  codecs.register_error that can handle ValueErrors.

  Type:      builtin_function_or_method

Answer (score 8):

[`base64.b16encode`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/base64.html#base64.b16encode) and [`base64.b16decode`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/base64.html#base64.b16decode) convert bytes to and from hex and work across all Python versions.  The [codecs approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16033232/) also works, but is less straightforward in Python 3.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! A cross-python version way of hex encoding & decoding. Thanks ^_^

`>>> import base64
>>> key = base64.b16encode(b'0123456789abcdef')
>>> base64.b16decode(key)
'0123456789abcdef'`

Answer (score 3):

Use hexlify - http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/binascii-module.html

Comment: It was shorter than "hexlificationize" :^)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another method:

```
s = 'hello'

h = ''.join([hex(ord(i)) for i in s]);

# outputs: '0x680x650x6c0x6c0x6f'
```

This basically splits the string into chars, does the conversion through `hex(ord(char))`, and joins the chars back together. In case you want the result without the prefix `0x` then do:

```
h = ''.join([str(hex(ord(i)))[2:4] for i in s]);

# outputs: '68656c6c6f'
```

Tested with Python 3.5.3.

Answer (score 1):

#### str to hex:

```
>>> "hello".encode().hex()
'68656c6c6f'
```

#### bytes to hex:

```
>>> b"hello".hex()
'68656c6c6f'
```

#### bytes from hex:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex("68656c6c6f")
b'hello'
```

#### str from hex:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex("68656c6c6f").decode()
'hello'
```