# Error with hex encode in Python 3.3

Tags: image, python-3.x, numpy, colors, hex

I am trying modify code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241929/python-find-dominant-most-common-color-in-an-image) to use in Python 3.3 (I installed Pillow, scipy and NumPy):

```
import struct
from PIL import Image
import scipy
import scipy.misc
import scipy.cluster

NUM_CLUSTERS = 5
print ('reading image')
im = Image.open("image.jpg")
im = im.resize((150, 150))      # optional, to reduce time
ar = scipy.misc.fromimage(im)
shape = ar.shape
ar = ar.reshape(scipy.product(shape[:2]), shape[2])

print ('finding clusters')
codes, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(ar, NUM_CLUSTERS)
print ('cluster centres:\n'), codes

vecs, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.vq(ar, codes)         # assign codes
counts, bins = scipy.histogram(vecs, len(codes))    # count occurrences

index_max = scipy.argmax(counts)                    # find most frequent
peak = codes[index_max]
colour = ''.join(chr(c) for c in peak).encode('hex')
print ('most frequent is %s (#%s)') % (peak, colour)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:/Users/User/Desktop/pyt33_pic.py", line 24, in <module>
  colour = ''.join(chr(c) for c in peak).encode('hex') LookupError: unknown encoding: hex
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `print` is a function in Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2.x the codec "hex_codec" is aliased to "hex". This alias is restored in 3.4. A bigger change is that a buffer to `bytes` encoding requires using `codecs.encode` in Python 3. Additionally, for string formatting you'll need to decode the result. For example:

```
>>> peak
array([131, 128, 124], dtype=uint8)

>>> codecs.encode(peak, 'hex_codec').decode('ascii')
'83807c'
```

Alternatively you can use the `format` function to individually convert the numbers to hex:

```
>>> ''.join(format(c, '02x') for c in peak)
'83807c'
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Your explanation really helped me.

Comment: The first example uses `peak` as a buffer, since it's an array of bytes (i.e. `np.uint8`). Otherwise, assuming all elements are in `range(256)`, you'd have to use something like `codecs.encode(bytes(c for c in peak), 'hex_codec')`. Using `format` is simpler.