# Python 3: Most common color in image kmeans data type match

Tags: python, colors, python-3.5

I am trying to adapt some python 2.4 code to 3.5. I am trying to use the top answer from this thread: [Python - Find dominant/most common color in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241929/python-find-dominant-most-common-color-in-an-image), but it's giving me trouble. This author also had trouble, but different trouble [Error with hex encode in Python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839730/error-with-hex-encode-in-python-3-3)

Specifically something to do with scipy and kmeans variable types? Here is the code and traceback. Your wisdom is appreciated! -S

```
import struct
from PIL import Image
import scipy
import scipy.misc
import scipy.cluster
import numpy as np

NUM_CLUSTERS = 3

print('reading image')
im = Image.open('image.jpg')
im = im.resize((150, 150))      # optional, to reduce time
ar = scipy.misc.fromimage(im)
shape = ar.shape
ar = ar.reshape(scipy.product(shape[:2]), shape[2])

print ('finding clusters')
print(ar)
print("Variable type:", type(ar))
codes, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(ar, NUM_CLUSTERS)
print('cluster centres:\n', codes)

vecs, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.vq(ar, codes)         # assign codes
counts, bins = scipy.histogram(vecs, len(codes))    # count occurrences
index_max = scipy.argmax(counts)                    # find most frequent
peak = codes[index_max]

colour = ''.join(format(c, '02x') for c in peak).encode('hex_codec')
print ('most frequent is %s (#%s)' % (peak, colour))
```

and the traceback is:

```
=========== RESTART: /Users/splash/Dropbox/PY/image-dom-color.py ============
reading image
finding clusters
[[255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]
 ..., 
 [255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]]
Variable type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/splash/Dropbox/PY/image-dom-color.py", line 20, in <module>
    codes, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(ar, NUM_CLUSTERS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/cluster/vq.py", line 568, in kmeans
    book, dist = _kmeans(obs, guess, thresh=thresh)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/cluster/vq.py", line 436, in _kmeans
    code_book, has_members = _vq.update_cluster_means(obs, obs_code, nc)
  File "scipy/cluster/_vq.pyx", line 347, in scipy.cluster._vq.update_cluster_means (scipy/cluster/_vq.c:4695)
TypeError: type other than float or double not supported
>>>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The stacktrace tells us that the only supported data types for `scipy.cluster._vq.update_cluster_means()` are `float` and `double`. Checking out scipy's source code confirms this:

```
def update_cluster_means(np.ndarray obs, np.ndarray labels, int nc):
    """
    The update-step of K-means. Calculate the mean of observations in each
    cluster.
    Parameters
    ----------
    obs : ndarray
        The observation matrix. Each row is an observation. Its dtype must be
        float32 or float64.
    ...
```

*Source: [_vq.pyx on GitHub](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/cf9ea6a1060710aba69e8991097b4cefbd725548/scipy/cluster/_vq.pyx)*

To solve your problem you first need to convert the input into a supported data type using [numpy.ndarray.astype()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
codes, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(ar.astype(float), NUM_CLUSTERS)
# Or:       = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(ar.astype('double'), NUM_CLUSTERS)
```

Comment: Thanks Johan - Got me past that part :) Working on the next bug now. I had tried to convert the variable a number of other ways with no luck. I really appreciate the tip!

Comment: If the next bug is related to printing the hex value of the color, it appears that you don't need the final `encode('hex_codec')`. It's also necessary to convert the result back into integers:

    `peak = peak.astype(int)`  
    `colour = ''.join(format(c, '02x') for c in peak)`  
    `print ('most frequent is %s (#%s)' % (peak, colour))`