# Scipy Kmeans exits with TypeError

Tags: python, scipy, runtime-error, k-means

When running the code below, I'm getting a TypeError that says:

"File "_vq.pyx", line 342, in scipy.cluster._vq.update_cluster_means
TypeError: type other than float or double not supported"

```
from PIL import Image
import scipy, scipy.misc, scipy.cluster

NUM_CLUSTERS = 5

im = Image.open('d:/temp/test.jpg')
ar = scipy.misc.fromimage(im)
shape = ar.shape
ar = ar.reshape(scipy.product(shape[:2]), shape[2])
codes, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(ar, NUM_CLUSTERS)
vecs, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.vq(ar, codes)
counts, bins = scipy.histogram(vecs, len(codes))

peak = codes[scipy.argmax(counts)]
print 'Most frequent color: %s (#%s)' % (peak, ''.join(chr(c) for c in peak).encode('hex'))
```

I have no idea how to fix this.

**Update:**

Full traceback:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\temp.py", line 110, in <module>
    codes, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2(ar, NUM_CLUSTERS)
  File "...\site-packages\scipy\cluster\vq.py", line 642, in kmeans2
    new_code_book, has_members = _vq.update_cluster_means(data, label, nc)
  File "_vq.pyx", line 342, in scipy.cluster._vq.update_cluster_means
TypeError: type other than float or double not supported`

Comment: This error-message is incomplete (probably tells you exactly which code-line does not work, although we could guess) and when recognizing this line, print out the type of the input, which might be for example uint8. It would also help to use an example with an image, we got access to. (and as a side-note: most people prefer sklearn's kmeans).

Comment: I've added the full traceback I'm seeing. It happens with all images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing:

```
ar = ar.reshape(scipy.product(shape[:2]), shape[2])
print(ar.dtype)
```

you will see, that you call kmeans with data of type **uint8**.

As kmeans, in theory, is defined on a d-dimensional *real* vector, scipy also does not like it (as given in the error)!

So just do:

```
ar = ar.reshape(scipy.product(shape[:2]), shape[2]).astype(float)
```

Casting like that is making my example run until the print, which also needs to be changed to reflect the given types.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works :) That would have taken me forever to find!