# What's the correct way to convert bytes to a hex string in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

What's the correct way to convert bytes to a hex string in Python 3?

I see claims of a `bytes.hex` method, `bytes.decode` codecs, and have tried [other](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#hex) possible functions of least astonishment without avail. I just want my bytes as hex!

Comment: "without avail"?  What **specific** problems or errors are you getting?  Please show code and errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340319/python-3-1-1-string-to-hex

Answer (score 745, accepted):

Since Python 3.5 this is finally no longer awkward:

```
>>> b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef'.hex()
'deadbeef'
```

and reverse:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('deadbeef')
b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef'
```

works also with the mutable `bytearray` type.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex

Comment: [`bytes.fromhex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex) is also available on Python 3.0+ (not just 3.5+). `bytes.hex()` is only on Python 3.5+.

Answer (score 109):

Use the `binascii` module:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify('foo'.encode('utf8'))
b'666f6f'
>>> binascii.unhexlify(_).decode('utf8')
'foo'
```

See this answer:
[Python 3.1.1 string to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340319/python-3-1-1-string-to-hex/2340358#2340358)

Comment: This is good. Mind boggling is that you can convert hex to bytes using bytes.fromhex(hex_str), but you cannot convert bytes to hex using bytes.tohex() - what is the rational in this?

Comment: I guess the relationship between bytes and hex isn't a property of either (which doesn't answer why fromhex is there). Seems like it wasn't just an oversight but something that was argued over: http://bugs.python.org/issue3532#msg70950.
Q: Would it hurt to have the tohex method of the bytes object to perform this task as well?
A: IMO, yes, it would. It complicates the code, and draws the focus away from the proper approach to data conversion (namely, functions - not methods).

Comment: Does this really answer the question? It doesn't return a hex `str` but a `bytes`. I know that the OP seems happy with the answer but won't be better to expand this answer to include `.decode("ascii")` also to convert it to a "string"

Comment: @ecerulm Updated to include encoding/decoding the `'foo'`. I left the `b'666f6f'`, though… a byte string is the most natural representation of encoded hex.

Comment: I was thinking that many people land on this question/answer looking for a way to printout a `bytes`. If you `print(b'666f6f')` you get the `b` in the printout. If you `.decode("ascii")` then you don't. Just thinking on how those that actually had a `bytes` (true binary with items > 128 , not an ascii string) an wanted to printout it.

Comment: @nagylzs: there is `.hex()` method in Python 3.5+

Comment: Great (although I think Python 3.5 was not available at the time the question was asked)

Answer (score 52):

Python has bytes-to-bytes [standard codecs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/codecs.html#binary-transforms) that perform convenient transformations like quoted-printable (fits into 7bits ascii), base64 (fits into alphanumerics), hex escaping, gzip and bz2 compression.  In Python 2, you could do:

```
b'foo'.encode('hex')
```

In Python 3, `str.encode` / `bytes.decode` are strictly for bytes<->str conversions. Instead, you can do this, which works across Python 2 and Python 3 (*s/encode/decode/g* for the inverse):

```
import codecs
codecs.getencoder('hex')(b'foo')[0]
```

Starting with Python 3.4, there is a less awkward option:

```
codecs.encode(b'foo', 'hex')
```

These misc codecs are also accessible inside their own modules (base64, zlib, bz2, uu, quopri, binascii); the API is less consistent, but for compression codecs it offers more control.

Comment: using python 3.3: `LookupError: unknown encoding: hex`

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: try ['hex_codec'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22465079/4279). Or just use `binascii.hexlify(b'foo')` directly

Answer (score 34):

New in python 3.8, you can pass a delimiter argument to the `hex` function, as in this example

```
>>> value = b'\xf0\xf1\xf2'
>>> value.hex('-')
'f0-f1-f2'
>>> value.hex('_', 2)
'f0_f1f2'
>>> b'UUDDLRLRAB'.hex(' ', -4)
'55554444 4c524c52 4142'
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex

Comment: This can be useful: `[f'0x{val}' for val in value.hex(' ', 2).split()]` gives something like `['0x2600', '0x9c00', '0x1900', '0x0c75']`

Answer (score 12):

The method `binascii.hexlify()` will convert `bytes` to a `bytes` representing the ascii hex string. That means that each byte in the input will get converted to two ascii characters. If you want a true `str` out then you can `.decode("ascii")` the result.

I included an snippet that illustrates it.

```
import binascii

with open("addressbook.bin", "rb") as f: # or any binary file like '/bin/ls'
    in_bytes = f.read()
    print(in_bytes) # b'\n\x16\n\x04'
    hex_bytes = binascii.hexlify(in_bytes) 
    print(hex_bytes) # b'0a160a04' which is twice as long as in_bytes
    hex_str = hex_bytes.decode("ascii")
    print(hex_str) # 0a160a04
```

from the hex string `"0a160a04"` to can come back to the `bytes` with `binascii.unhexlify("0a160a04")` which gives back `b'\n\x16\n\x04'`

Answer (score 7):

```
import codecs
codecs.getencoder('hex_codec')(b'foo')[0]
```

works in Python 3.3 (so "hex_codec" instead of "hex").

Comment: Perhaps interestingly, in Python 3.4 "hex" or "hex_codec" works fine.

Answer (score 6):

it can been used the format specifier `%x02` that format and output a hex value. For example:

```
>>> foo = b"tC\xfc}\x05i\x8d\x86\x05\xa5\xb4\xd3]Vd\x9cZ\x92~'6"
>>> res = ""
>>> for b in foo:
...     res += "%02x" % b
... 
>>> print(res)
7443fc7d05698d8605a5b4d35d56649c5a927e2736
```

Comment: According to me, it is the best answer because it works with every Python version and does not need any import. Yet, I would better display hexa strings  in upper case `res.upper()`

Comment: No need for `upper()`!. You can control case by `x` or `X`: `'%02X' % 79 == '4F'`

Answer (score 4):

OK, the following answer is slightly beyond-scope if you only care about Python 3, but this question is the first Google hit even if you don't specify the Python version, so here's a way that works on both Python 2 *and* Python 3.

I'm also interpreting the question to be about converting bytes to the `str` type: that is, bytes-y on Python 2, and Unicode-y on Python 3.

Given that, the best approach I know is:

```
import six

bytes_to_hex_str = lambda b: ' '.join('%02x' % i for i in six.iterbytes(b))
```

The following assertion will be true for either Python 2 or Python 3, assuming you haven't activated the `unicode_literals` future in Python 2:

```
assert bytes_to_hex_str(b'jkl') == '6a 6b 6c'
```

(Or you can use `''.join()` to omit the space between the bytes, etc.)

Comment: I've found this useful when supporting Python 3.7, which does _not_ have a `sep` arg in `bytes.hex`. At time of writing, 3.7 is still a supported version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert b'\x61' to 97 or '0x61', you can try this:

```
[python3.5]
>>>from struct import *
>>>temp=unpack('B',b'\x61')[0] ## convert bytes to unsigned int
97
>>>hex(temp) ##convert int to string which is hexadecimal expression
'0x61'
```

Reference:https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html

Comment: Somehow helps me with esp32

Comment: Absolutly, as @TejasTank says. This only method working on MicroPhyton where a lot of libraries are not available.