# Byte Array to Hex String

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, arrays

I have data stored in a byte array. How can I convert this data into a hex string?

Example of my byte array:

```
array_alpha = [ 133, 53, 234, 241 ]
```

Comment: related: [What's the correct way to convert bytes to a hex string in Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6624453/4279)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Using [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format):

```
>>> array_alpha = [ 133, 53, 234, 241 ]
>>> print ''.join('{:02x}'.format(x) for x in array_alpha)
8535eaf1
```

or using [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format)

```
>>> print ''.join(format(x, '02x') for x in array_alpha)
8535eaf1
```

> *Note:* In the format statements, the `02` means it will pad with up to 2 leading `0`s if necessary. This is important since `[0x1, 0x1, 0x1] i.e. (0x010101)` would be formatted to `"111"` instead of `"010101"`

or using [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) with [`binascii.hexlify`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(bytearray(array_alpha))
'8535eaf1'
```

---

Here is a benchmark of above methods in Python 3.6.1:

```python
from timeit import timeit
import binascii

number = 10000

def using_str_format() -> str:
    return "".join("{:02x}".format(x) for x in test_obj)

def using_format() -> str:
    return "".join(format(x, "02x") for x in test_obj)

def using_hexlify() -> str:
    return binascii.hexlify(bytearray(test_obj)).decode('ascii')

def do_test():
    print("Testing with {}-byte {}:".format(len(test_obj), test_obj.__class__.__name__))
    if using_str_format() != using_format() != using_hexlify():
        raise RuntimeError("Results are not the same")

    print("Using str.format       -> " + str(timeit(using_str_format, number=number)))
    print("Using format           -> " + str(timeit(using_format, number=number)))
    print("Using binascii.hexlify -> " + str(timeit(using_hexlify, number=number)))

test_obj = bytes([i for i in range(255)])
do_test()

test_obj = bytearray([i for i in range(255)])
do_test()
```

Result:

```
Testing with 255-byte bytes:
Using str.format       -> 1.459474583090427
Using format           -> 1.5809937679100738
Using binascii.hexlify -> 0.014521426401399307
Testing with 255-byte bytearray:
Using str.format       -> 1.443447684109402
Using format           -> 1.5608712609513171
Using binascii.hexlify -> 0.014114164661833684
```

Methods using `format` do provide additional formatting options, as example separating numbers with spaces `" ".join`, commas `", ".join`, upper-case printing `"{:02X}".format(x)`/`format(x, "02X")`, etc., but at a cost of great performance impact.

Comment: Yours last trick give me `b'8535eaf1'`  on my system, what is `b` ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, Are you using Python 3.x? In Python 3.x binascii.hexlify return `bytes` objects.

Comment: Yes, my Python is 3.3.2. -- `return bytes objects` - byte object means? something like `int` object?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, See [`Built-in Types - Bytes`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes).

Comment: For anyone else reading this: convert b'8535eaf1' to '8535eaf1' with b'8535eaf1'.decode('ascii')

Comment: @mkingston, You can omit the encoding: `b'8535eaf1'.decode()`

Comment: bytearray(array_alpha).hex()

Comment: @Magnetron `AttributeError: 'bytearray' object has no attribute 'hex'`

Comment: The question is tagged python2.7. Python3 is off topic.

Answer (score 71):

Consider the [hex() method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) of the `bytes` type on Python 3.5 and up:

```
>>> array_alpha = [ 133, 53, 234, 241 ]
>>> print(bytes(array_alpha).hex())
8535eaf1
```

EDIT: it's also much faster than `hexlify` (modified @falsetru's benchmarks above)

```
from timeit import timeit
N = 10000
print("bytearray + hexlify ->", timeit(
    'binascii.hexlify(data).decode("ascii")',
    setup='import binascii; data = bytearray(range(255))',
    number=N,
))
print("byte + hex          ->", timeit(
    'data.hex()',
    setup='data = bytes(range(255))',
    number=N,
))
```

Result:

```
bytearray + hexlify -> 0.011218150997592602
byte + hex          -> 0.005952142993919551
```

Comment: Note that bytearray + hexlify returns data as bytes (b' 34567890aed'), while byte + hex returns it as a string (34567890aed)

Comment: It also takes an optional argument to specify a separator, so bytes(array_alpha).hex(' '), prints every byte with a space separating them

Answer (score 15):

```
hex_string = "".join("%02x" % b for b in array_alpha)
```

Comment: thanks for providing an answer that also works with older versions of python (forced to use 2.5.1 here)

Comment: @Baldrickk Yeah, it's amazing how many off-topic answers there are. The question is tagged `python2.7`.

Answer (score 4):

Or, if you are a fan of functional programming:

```
>>> a = [133, 53, 234, 241]
>>> "".join(map(lambda b: format(b, "02x"), a))
8535eaf1
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a numpy array, you can do the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([133, 53, 234, 241])
>>> a.astype(np.uint8).data.hex()
'8535eaf1'
```

Comment: This requires the import of an external library and does not address the fact that OP is working with bytes. This is not the most robust solution.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Removed the "robust solution" part. I still think a numpy solution is useful for others coming here from google (it's much more common to have data in a numpy matrix rather than as a byte array).

Comment: I still think that it is a good idea to answer OP's question instead of making a general post that may be useful to someone. It is very unlikely that someone searching Google for how to process numpy arrays is going to come to the question titled "Byte Array to Hex String".

Comment: helped me as well. beautiful.

Comment: This just a worse way of spelling `bytearray([133, 53, 234, 241]).hex()`

Comment: @Eric Unless you are starting off with a numpy "byte array".

Comment: I think I misintepreted your answer. You mean "you can do this _if you have_ a numpy array", not "you can do this with numpy _as a tool_"

Answer (score 0):

### For Python 3.6 and later: use f-strings

Python 3.6 and beyond supports f-strings (aka "formatted string literals") like this:

```
array_alpha = [ 133, 53, 234, 241 ]
>>> print(' '.join(f'{x:02x}' for x in array_alpha))
85 35 ea f1
```