# ascii characters in bytearray instead of hex values

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, can-bus

```
import can

bus = can.Bus(interface='socketcan',
              channel='can0',
              bitrate=500000)

for msg in bus:
    print("{}: {}".format(msg.arbitration_id, msg.data))
```

As a result of the code above, I get a bytearray with some ascii characters. For example

bytearray(b'**@**\x1f@\x00\x00\xf4\x00\x00')

bytearray(b'\x00\x90**o**\x10')

and here below their equivalent.

40 1f 40 00 00 f4 00 00

00 90 6f 10

How can i get pure hex values without "@" and "o" in bytearray?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you check `binascii.hexlify(bytearray(...))` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19210442/3727050)?

Comment: This is just a printing issue as python replaces know hexcodes by known printable characters to shorten the output, f.e. `0x13` => `\n`,`0x10` => `\t` etc. You still have "the hex values" in your bytearray