# Python bytes to string for SQL Server rowversion data type

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm reading a [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) data type from SQL Server using Python and getting back a bytes representation like `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x9c'`.

How can I decode this?

I've tried a few codecs but it's not returning the expected result. Decoded value should be `0x000000000000189c`. I'm not seeing much on this data type and what the encoding is so I'm kinda lost.

Edit:
I didn't need to decode, I needed to convert from bytes to hex (doh)

Comment: What do you mean "how do decode it?"

Comment: There is nothing to decode, it's just a bunch of bytes that identify the LSN when the row was last updated. Perhaps you just want to convert the bytes to a hex string representation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210414/byte-array-to-hex-string

Comment: Ah I see, I just need to convert to hex. How do I get the first 0x or is that always the first two characters?

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken, I don't need to decode. Calling `hex()` on the bytes gets a close representation as to what it is in SQL Server

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x9c'.hex()
'000000000000189c'
```