# converting hex string to ascii

Tags: python, hex, encode, python-2.x

I have a string that looks like

```
\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00q~5\xf1\xacHhA\xd7[\x18>\x9erCA\x13\xf5Q\xa3\xadHhA\x17V\xde\x9f\x97rCA\xeb\x8a\x90\xea\xadHhA\x11\x1e\xaf5\x92rCA\xeb\x8a\x90\xea\xadHhA\xad\x8c\x8a\xff\x8drCA\xd7\xd5/\x0e\xaeHhA\xedPkc\x8arCAY\xe2\x8a\x07\xafHhAj|7_\x84rCA\x0f\x0e\x08\x96\xafHhA\x93\xcc\xfe\xc0}rCA\xe7\xa3F\xdd\xafHhAQ\xac\xd0VxrCA\xe7\xa3F\xdd\xafHhA\x80%\xb7TurCA\x0f
```

I'd like to convert it to binary encoded hex like

```
0102000020110F0000B802000060CB38045D344E4167866F87E25C4D41C88730520F344E4133683205B35C4D41A6719BE3C2334E41F2A9DA95665C4D41A2D14537D1334E415CFC777B285C4D41528DB9E018344E4180C29B0A075C4D4117D477C186344E41C1E177EEF35B4D41D83AC468F9344E41B9C5ECB5F85B4D41FED020BD32354E4178A8C9EEC85B4D4188F6371241354E41A60F877E7C5B4D41FDF0AE8337354E41AF16059E0E5B4D41EE45D6850C354E41B0F6E4D9B35A4D41B2644B87B6344E41ACAEE167
```

in python 2.7

As an added bonus, anyone know whats the `q~5\xf1\xacHhA\xd7[\x18>\` part that doesn't look like hex :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to convert bytes to a hex string in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624453/whats-the-correct-way-to-convert-bytes-to-a-hex-string-in-python-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> '\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01...'.encode('hex')
'0103000000012e2e2e'
```

> As an added bonus...

It's hex values that fall within ASCII characters. Since you have a bytestring, values within ASCII are represented as text.