# How to replace `c2a0` with none character in python3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace, byte

I want to convert `b'\xc2\xa0\x38'` into `b'x38'` in python3.

```
b'\xc2\xa0\x38'.replace(u'\xc2\xa0',"")
b'\xc2\xa0\x38'.replace(u'\xc2a0',"")

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

In the webpage,the `c2 a0` means NO-BREAK SPACE whose unicode point is U+00A0       .

```
Unicode  code point character   UTF-8  (hex.)   name
U+00A0                          c2 a0           NO-BREAK SPACE
```

Notice: `c2a0` is unprintable , character column is blank here.

[relationship on unicode point,character,utf-8](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)

How to  convert `b'\xc2\xa0\x38'` into `b'\x38'` with replace method?

Comment: By passing bytes-like objects instead of strings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were already almost there:

```
b'\xc2\xa0\x38'.replace(b'\xc2\xa0',b'')
```

Comment: How to make `b'8'` displayed as `b'\x38'`?

Comment: `print(''.join([r'\x'+hex(b)[2:] for b in b'\xc2\xa0\x38'.replace(b'\xc2\xa0',b'')]))`

Answer (score 4):

```
b'\xc2\xa0\x38'.replace(u'\xc2\xa0',"")
b'\xc2\xa0\x38'.replace(u'\xc2a0',"")
```

Since `b'\xc2\xa0\x38'` is a [bytes object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects), you cannot use string methods on it. So when you call `.replace()` on it, you are not calling `str.replace` but [`bytes.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.replace). While those two look and behave very similarly, they still operate on different types:

`str.replace` replaces a *substring* inside of a *string* with another *string*. And `bytes.replace` replaces a *sub-bytestring* inside of a *bytestring* with another *bytestring*. So the types of all arguments always match:

```
str.replace(str, str)
bytes.replace(bytes, bytes)
```

So in order to replace something inside of a bytes string, you need to pass bytes objects:

```
>>> b'\xc2\xa0\x38'.replace(b'\xc2\xa0', b'')
b'8'
>>> b'\xc2\xa0\x38'.replace(b'\xc2a0', b'')
b'\xc2\xa08'
```

> How to make `b'8'` displayed as `b'\x38'`?

You generall cannot do that. `b'8'` and `b'\x38'` are both equal to another:

```
>>> b'8' == b'\x38'
True
```

Both contain the same single byte value, a `0x38`. It’s just that there are multiple ways to represent that content as a bytes literal in Python. Just like you can write `10`, `0xA`, `0b1010` or `0o12` to refer to the *same* `int` object with the decimal value of 10, you can describe a bytes object in multiple ways.

Now, when you use the interactive Python REPL, when you just write `b'\x38'`, then Python will interpret that bytes literal, create a bytes object with the single byte 0x38, and then the REPL will print out the `repr()` of that bytes object. And the repr() of bytes objects just happen to attempt to use ASCII letters whenever possible.

There is no way to change this, but there’s also no *need* to change that. The `b'8'` that you see is just *one* representation of the same bytes object. And if you use that object and do something with it (e.g. write it to a file, transform it, or send over the network), then it’s the actual bytes that are sent, and not some string representation of the bytes object.

If you however want to actually *print* the bytes object, you can deliberately convert it into a string using your favorite representation. For example, if you want a hex representation of your bytes string, you could use [one of the many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6624453/216074) to do that:

```
>>> print(b'8'.hex())
38
>>> print(b'\x38'.hex())
38
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that data being read from a file? Maybe you opened the file in binary mode:

```
with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
```

This means that the data read from the file is returned as `bytes` object, not `str`.

If that is so, try to open the file as a textfile instead by replacing the `'rb'` mode with `'r'`.