# How to retrieve timestamp from SQL Server using python?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server-2012, pyodbc, python-3.7

I have written a query to retrieve a row from a table in SQL Server. I am using pyodbc and python 3.7 here.

I am getting the following:

```
(18, 3, 1, 'test', 'test', None, Decimal('0.0000'), Decimal('0.0000'), 0, 0, b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xe7\xaco')
The last value b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xe7\xaco' is the timestamp of the row which looks like follows in the database "0x000000000FE7AC6F".
```

I want to be either able to retrieve the timestamp as is or be able to convert `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xe7\xaco'` into the proper timestamp value before calling another query which uses the value.

Comment: could you describe the table for me and post the code you are using to access it?

Comment: The conversion problem has been [answered earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16033232/9921041) for Python 2 as well as 3. (It is easier in Python 3)

Comment: @Ayush Vatsyayan thank you for editing my question.

Comment: @Kapil, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @ferdtomale, it is a simple table. I used pyodbc.connect() and the cursor available through it to query the table directly from python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using python3, the conversion is relatively easy.

```
s=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xe7\xaco'
'0x'+s.hex().upper()
```

has output

```
'0x000000000FE7AC6F'
```