# How can I convert a type bytes into eight bits in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I have a file with consecutive bytes I'm reading.

Most of these bytes I unpack 4 or 8 at a time using stuct.unpack into floats and integers, which works fine.

```
from struct import unpack
from sys import stdin

read_data = stdin.buffer.read()
integer_number = unpack("i", read_data[0:4])
double_number = unpack("d", read_data[4:12])
```

But one of the Bytes needs to be interpreted as 8 individual bits.

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html) there doesn't seem to be a way to convert a byte into something like two hex digits or eight binary.

I've also tried interpreting the byte as a string, which works with small numbers, but gives me stranger results the higher the number gets.

This question has been answered on SO for many languages but I couldn't find a Python3 solution.

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624453/whats-the-correct-way-to-convert-bytes-to-a-hex-string-in-python-3/6624521):

```
hex_number = read_data[12:13].hex()
```