# How to decode a REG_BINARY from Windows registry?

Tags: python, windows, registry, decode

[The value I want to decode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/975QT.png)

```py
import winreg

def readvalue1():
    key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'' + str(readreg1()), 0, winreg.KEY_READ)
    for i in range(0, winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[1]):
        return winreg.EnumValue(key, i)

print(readvalue1()[1])
```

Output :

```
b'\xef\xf7\xfa\xf4\xf3\xfd&+\x00\xfd+\x03\xfc\xfe\x06\x040\x00'
```

how can I decode output to the format in the photo using winreg ?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Comment: @AMC I didn't share code or error as an image I added the photo of the Value because it was necessary to question.

Comment: The exact same reasons apply, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the correct way to convert bytes to a hex string in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624453/whats-the-correct-way-to-convert-bytes-to-a-hex-string-in-python-3)