# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte django

Tags: python, django, encryption, byte, createfile

so i have variable contains in bytes and i want to save it to str. but how to do it? i tried various kinds of ways, but always got error

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte

i want to save the result encrypt file to text file. so i have the proof it the file was encrypt. here;s my ways 1:

```
 def create_file(f):
     response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/plain")
     response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.txt'

     filename = f
     print(filename)
     name_byte = codecs.decode(filename)
     print(name_byte)

     return response
```

my ways 2 :

```
def create_file(enc):
    with open("file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        enc = enc.decode('utf-8')
        f.write(enc)
```

my ways 3:

```
def create_file(f):
    file = open("file.txt", "w")
    f = f.decode('utf-8')
    download = file.write(f)
    file.close()
    print(download)

    return download
```

f = b'\xa0\x0e\xdc\x14'
f is the return result of encrypt

i called the function :

```
#in views
download = create_file(enc)
           print(download)

#in urls
path("create_file", views.create_file, name="create_file"),

#in html
<a href="{% url 'create_file' %}">
```

Comment: very common problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string

Comment: not works. if i use "utf-8", i got error message 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: invalid continuation byte @D.L

Comment: okay.  try for `hex bytes`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624453/whats-the-correct-way-to-convert-bytes-to-a-hex-string-in-python-3

Comment: not the result i want, what i want is i can save b'\x08\xb3Q\x90' to txt file. if i use hex then i just get the result of encrypt. @D.L

Comment: have amended the answer according to the last comment (`save line to file`)...

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "have variable contains in bytes and i want to save it to str" makes no sense at all. bytes and str are different data types serving different purposes. bytes holds a byte stream while str hold abstract text. Yes, bytes can also hold textual info encoded in some text encoding like UTF-8, but that is only a specific case. If, for example, your bytes hold a JPEG image then converting it to str does not make any sense simply because it's not text. So if your encrypted file contains a byte stream you need to treat it as such. It's not text any more until you decrypt it.

So the only thing you can do is to save your byte stream as is using the binary file mode:

```
v = b'\xa0\x0e\xdc\x14'
with open ('/path', 'wb') as fo:
    fo.write(v)
```

The same applies to sending the encrypted file as Django response:

```
response = HttpResponse(v, content_type="application/octet-stream")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.bin'
```

Comment: but it not works

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to write the entire line to file then all you have to do is convert to string.

So this would work:

```py
v = b'\xa0\x0e\xdc\x14'

with open("C:/test/output.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(v))
```

The result is a text file like this:

[image]

Comment: i got error : The view MusicLockApp.views.create_file didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. how to return to html??

Comment: how did you implement this into your code (maybe a new question) as the above works (using windows file path).

Comment: please check again my update

Comment: the original question was how to write the text, so are you now asking how to create the file in a new path ?

Comment: im asking how to create file contains with b'\xa0\x0e\xdc\x14'

Comment: you can use the same code.  If the file does not exist then then it will be created (so long as the folder exists). If you are asking how to create a `new folder`, then this might be best as a new question.

Comment: how to called that func to html?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73601131/how-to-return-result-to-html-django
here's new question. if it's work, then i will check this question