# how to return result to html django

Tags: python, html, django, text-files, createfile

I want to make text file contains with `b'Y\xf5\x11m'` *(it's result from encryption)*. And I want *txt* file can be downloaded using html.

But I got next error when I return it:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here's the code:

```py
def create_file(f):
    with open("file.txt", 'w') as file:
        download = file.write(str(f))
        print(download)
        return download
```

I called that func like this:

```py
#in views
def homepage(request):
    form = AudioForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AudioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            last_audio = Audio_store.objects.all().last()
            plaintext = Audio_store.objects.all().values_list('password').last()
            key = Audio_store.objects.all().values_list('key').last()
            pt = plaintext[0]
            ky = key[0]
            print(pt)
            print(ky)
            context={'form':form, 'last_audio':last_audio}
            enc = encrypt(ky, pt)
            print(enc)
            download = create_file(enc)
            print(download)
            return render(request, "homepage.html", context)

    context={'form':form}
    return render(request, "homepage.html", context=context)

#in urls
path("create_file", views.create_file, name="create_file"),

#in html
<a href="{% url 'create_file' %}">
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyjyv.png)

Comment: you are getting error from somewhere else, can you add full traceback here?

Comment: probably whole view-code here can be goot too.

Comment: i was update all view code @DivyaPrakash

Comment: i was add all view code @MaximDanilov

Comment: Thanks for adding view code but still traceback is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

you define function create_file, this function:

```
def create_file(f):
    with open("file.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(f))
        return file
```

This function get as parameter any information and write it in file.

After that you define url:

```
path("create_file", views.create_file, name="create_file"),
```

it means:
you have in view function 'create_file', which take `request` as first call parameter and returns `HtmlResponseObject`.

I don't see any view in your code, which get `request`, and sended back file as `HtmlResponseObject.body`.

I can only imagine:

in path:

```
path("create_file", views.FileView.as_view(), name="create_file"),
```

in views.py:

```
class FileView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('here your text to write in file', content_type='text/plain', headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=file.txt'})
```

It tested and work on django 4.1

Comment: so how to send back file to html? maybe i was wrong in url

Comment: i update answer

Comment: and how to declare View?

Comment: ??  In answer I give you a whole code. Did you understand my answer ?

Comment: sorry about the View. but i got error : FileView.get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'. i use all your code

Comment: How you call it?

Comment: i don't call anything. i think it will works automatic.

Comment: ok. i tested it on my locale: http://localhost:8000/create_file gives me file.txt. I update answer too. If it not works by you - probably i can not help any more.

Comment: how you call it? and where to call it