# Converting hexidecimal in byte form straight to a string

Tags: python

Is there a way to decode hexadecimal values in byte form directly into a string?
For example, I'm trying to convert `b'\x02\x08\x01\x00\x06\x0b'` into "28106b". It's weird but I'm required to do it this way because of the specs of the project that this code is a part of.

I received the first set of bytes using the bytes() method in Python. I tried to use `.decode()` and `.fromhex()`, but was given back a string with the ASCII correlation of the values.

Still relatively new to the language, so if I could get some advice on how to properly resolve this issue I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the correct way to convert bytes to a hex string in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624453/whats-the-correct-way-to-convert-bytes-to-a-hex-string-in-python-3)

Comment: @Will Are you trying to convert `b'\x02\x08\x01\x00\x06\x0b'` to `28106b` or to `02080100060b`? If it's later, you can use `.hex()` and you should be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer - try to use:

```
''.join('{:x}'.format(ch) for ch in b'\x02\x08\x01\x00\x06\x0b')
```

Explanation:

```
[ch for ch in b'\x02\x08\x01\x00\x06\x0b']
```

would yield a list of *numbers* `[2, 8, 1, 0, 6, 11]`, which we just need to format as hexadecimal *strings*, thus

```
['{:x}'.format(ch) for ch in b'\x02\x08\x01\x00\x06\x0b']
```

would yield `['2', '8', '1', '0', '6', 'b']`, which we now collect into a single string with the aforementioned code

```
''.join('{:x}'.format(ch) for ch in b'\x02\x08\x01\x00\x06\x0b')
```

would yield `"28106b"` string

Comment: f-string variant: `out = ''.join(f'{c:x}' for c in b'\x02\x08\x01\x00\x06\x0b')`. And yours could be rewritten with `map`: `''.join(map('{:x}'.format, b'\x02\x08\x01\x00\x06\x0b'))` ;)

Comment: Using `[ch for ch in b'\x02\x08\x01\x00\x06\x0b']` was what I needed, thx

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate over the byte string you get `int` variable back.

Use that as an index in a convertion array/string

```py
inp = b'\x02\x08\x01\x00\x06\x0b'
toHex ='0123456789abcdef'
outp = ''.join(toHex[c] for c in inp)
print(outp)
```