# Hex value converts to wrong code in Python

Tags: python-3.x, binary, hex, ascii, bytestream

I'm trying to use Python to send Byte stream commands to an RFID Module.

The device requires an example command:

```
b'\xa0\x06\x01\x72'
```

When I save this and print it to the console, it shows instead as:

```
b'\xa0\x06\x01r'
```

I've tried using multiple functions but all return the same:

```
>>> bytearray(b'x72')
'r'

>>> btyes.fromhex('72')
'r'

>>> array.array('B', [114]).tobytes()
'r'
```

All hex codes from 0x01-0x7F are shown to ASCII characters when executing the code.

Is it possible to force Python to display and therefore send the actual hex value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the correct way to convert bytes to a hex string in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624453/whats-the-correct-way-to-convert-bytes-to-a-hex-string-in-python-3)

Comment: They bytes are the exact same, so unless the the device expects a string representation for of the python-`repr` of a bytestring only including hex-escape sequences, everything is working correctly.

Comment: Thanks @MegaIng I literally just figured this out. This just confirms what i thought.