# Convert a byte stream from a smartmeter to a string

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, byte

From a smartmeter I receive a bytestream via USB IR Sensor on a Raspberry PI like this:

CHAR =  b'\x00\x86\x1b\x1b\x1b\x1b\x01\x01\x01\x01v\x05\x18\xe0\x99:b\x00b\x00rc\x01\x01v\x01\x01\x05\x08J\xdd\xbe\x0b\n\x01ISK\x00\x044\xb9Zrb\x01e\x08J\xe1\xf4b\x01c\x15\xb9\x00v\x05\x18\xe0\x99;b\x00b\x00rc\x07\x01w\x01\x0b\n\x01ISK\x00\x044\xb9Z\x07\x01\x00b\n\xff\xffrb\x01e\x08J\xe1\xf4t'

CHAR  is <class 'bytes'>

converting in Python2 like this:

```
data = ''
char = port.read()
data = data + char.encode('HEX')
```

works fine

How can I convert in Python3 ?

After conversion it should looks like this:

```
# 1b1b1b1b0101010176050033b18162006200726301017601010500113b2b0b0a0
# 149534b000434b95a72620165001137286201634e120076050033b182620062007  .....
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/temperatur/Smartmeter.py", line 72, in <module
data = data + char.encode('HEX') # Original in Python 2
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: A possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624453/whats-the-correct-way-to-convert-bytes-to-a-hex-string-in-python-3

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, the bytes.hex() method is commonly used for converting bytes to the hex format

```
data = b'Hello, World!'
print(data.hex())
```

Comment: probably important to note that it is a `str` type now in Python 3. Which is equivalent to Python 2 `unicode` (`str` in Python 2 is equivalent to Python 3 `byte`)