# Decoding a Unicode string; what does that mean and how can I avoid it?

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm looking for a simple way of converting a user-supplied string to UTF-8. It doesn't have to be very smart; it should handle all ASCII byte strings and all Unicode strings (2.x `unicode`, 3.x `str`).

Since `unicode` is gone in 3.x and `str` changed meaning, I thought it might be a good idea to check for the presence of a `decode` method and call that without arguments to let Python figure out what to do based on the locale, instead of doing `isinstance` checks. Turns out that's a not a good idea at all:

```
>>> u"één"
u'\xe9\xe9n'
>>> u"één".decode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-36-85c1b388bd1b>", line 1, in <module>
    u"één".decode()
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My question is two-fold:

1. Why is there a `unicode.decode` method at all? I thought Unicode strings were considered "not encoded". This looks like a sure way of getting doubly encoded strings.
2. How do I tackle this problem in a way that is forward-compatible with Python 3?

Comment: It's precisely warts like the decode method on Unicode strings that Python 3 fixes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not useful to speak of "decoding" a unicode string. You want to *en*code it to bytes. `unicode.decode` is solely there for historical reasons; its semantics are meaningless. Therefore, it has been removed in Python 3.

**However**, the `encode`/`decode` semantics have historically been extended to include (character) string-to-string or byte-to-bytes encodings such as rot13 or bzip2. In Python 3.1, these pseudo encodings were removed, and [reintroduced in Python 3.2](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

In general, you should design your interfaces so that they either accept character or byte strings. An interface that accepts both (for reasons other than backwards compatibility) is a code smell, hard to test, prone to bugs (what if someone passes UTF-16 bytes?) and has questionable semantics in the first place.

If you must have an interface that accepts both character and byte strings, you can check for the presence of the `decode` method in Python 3. If you want your code to work in 2.x as well, [you'll have to use `isinstance`](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/#decode-early).

Comment: Just what I thought. But then, how do I tackle the problem of going from any `basestring` to UTF-8, without `isinstance`?

Comment: Updated the answer. That's a problem that shouldn't occur in the first place - you should know what you're getting passed. I'm afraid you'll have to use `isinstance` if you want Python 2 and 3 compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion between str and unicode is not the only purpose of encode/decode.  There are also codecs.

For example (in Python 2):

```
>>> u'123'.encode('hex')
'313233'
>>> '313233'.decode('hex')
'123'
>>> u'313233'.decode('hex')
'123'
```

I'm not sufficiently familiar with Python 3 to be able to say whether or not this works there.

Comment: Wow, +1 for the complete surprise.

Comment: "hex" for string-to-string conversoins is only available in 2.x; it [has been removed in 3.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340319/python-3-1-1-string-to-hex).

Answer (score 1):

1. The Unicode object has a decode() method because it inherits from basestring and basestring has one, so Unicdode has to have one as well.
2. You tackle the problem by never decoding Unicode strings, in Python 2 or Python 3. As you note, it makes no sense to do so. So don't.

How then do you handle this in a compatible wait in Python 2 and Python 3? well, you don't use strings for binary data, you use `bytes`. They have a decode() method that works in all versions of Python.

For more information on this see http://python3porting.com/noconv.html and also http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/unconfusing-unicode-what-is-unicode/