# python crypto: DES CTR decryption

Tags: python, cryptography, counter, des

i have the following code by atomicinf found here: [atomicinf's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656045/pycrypto-incrementing-ctr-mode) ! the code is:

```
import Crypto.Cipher.AES
import Crypto.Util.Counter

key = "0123456789ABCDEF" # replace this with a sensible value, preferably the output of a hash
iv = "0000000000009001" # replace this with a RANDOMLY GENERATED VALUE, and send this with the ciphertext!

plaintext = "Attack at dawn" # replace with your actual plaintext

ctr = Crypto.Util.Counter.new(128, initial_value=long(iv.encode("hex"), 16))

cipher = Crypto.Cipher.AES.new(key, Crypto.Cipher.AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
print cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
```

my question is: how does the decryption work? (obviously i have to import the counter manually or save the current one somewhere) and second what about DES? i know that it has smaller counter but how do i define it?

Comment: Random 64 bit nonces are too short to be reliably unique. (OK it doesn't really matter, since DES is cheap to brute-force)

Comment: i know its weak but i dont care, i am a student and i am not going to apply it anywhere. i have just made a program for encry-decry DES in all modes but i just cant get CTR right... this counter thing is annoying me...

Answer (score 1):

Decryption for CTR mode works in the same way as encryption, i.e. to decrypt you should call 'encrypt' the second time.
That's because in CTR mode IV is incremented for each next block and encrypted with AES algorithm, and result than xored with cleartext. Xoring it again returns cleartext.