# Removing non-hex from bytes

Tags: python, byte

I have a data stream from a robotic arm which looks like the one shown below. However, I would receive additional characters from the source controller. How would I be able to remove these undesirable characters?

**Datastream:**
b'\x00\x00\x04\xe6\x10\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\xd8c\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfb\x01@\x06\xca\xf1!\xfdD\x9b@\x06\xca\xe7\'\x15k\xa7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00=\xb2

**Desired outcome:**
b'\x00\x00\x04\xe6\x10\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd8\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfb\x01\x06\xca\xf1\xfdD\x9b\x06\xca\xe7\x15k\xa7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb2

-EDIT-
The current code I have now does not remove the undesired characters

```
import socket
import struct
import time
HOST = '192.168.1.10'
PORT = 300002
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
data = s.recv(89)
data2 = struct.unpack("!iBiBQ7?2B2diB3d4fB", data)
print(data2)
s.close()
```

Comment: Please post what you ve tried so far and someone can critique on that. Asking how to code a problem is too broad. Welcome to SO.

Comment: What defines an "additional character" -- and why do you want to remove them? Surely they are part of the data sequence? PS the symbol rendered as "`@`" is just `\x40`, you knew that right?

Comment: Here at SO, we do not write your code. We just suggest how to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The datastream should only contain hex codes but what I am receiving is more than that such as \x9b@ where the @ is not part of what I expect from the datastream

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will try to ask the question better next time.

Comment: This is and was a perfectly good question even before the code was added.  The code is completely redundant. The question stems from lack of understanding of how python works with byte objects, which can be perfectly resolved by an answer. Sadly the question was downvoted and buried by the sands of time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python bytes literal has extra characters that aren't hex, but alter the value of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862497/python-bytes-literal-has-extra-characters-that-arent-hex-but-alter-the-value-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't specified why you think the characters are undesirable, I will assume that you think the extraneous characters are "undesirable" whereas they are actually important.

```
"@" has a hex value 0x40
"D" has a hex value 0x44
```

etc.

Search for ASCII or ANSI to see why.

The characters are printed because you are displaying the values as a string.
In the computer's memory they are still hex numbers!

The same stream of bytes can be expressed either as a string, or be read as numbers.
For example, you might want to read them as octets (bytes), or as `int`s or as  single-precision floats.

### EDIT

for example, you will notice that byte 18 is "`c`". So notice that the ASCII code `ord('c')=99`, or `0x63`.

To view the characters as integer values, you can do this:

```
[ord(x) for x in mystream]
```

and to display in hexadecimal

```
[hex(ord(x)) for x in mystream]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the method above. However I do not think this is the datastream should only contain numbers. For example: \x00\x00\x04\xe6 should be 0,0,4230, but now after conversion i get 98,39,92,120. sorry for the silly question.

Comment: You appear to be using a struct conversion with a format string. Basically this converts your byte stream into interpretable numbers. `i` takes the first 4 bytes and lumps them together into a single integer. the stream `[0,0,4,230]` should convert to `1254`. However, the data you posted is only 65 bytes, not 89, so there must be some bytes missing?

Comment: The entire datastream has about 577 bytes and i just took out part of the entire sequence.I am given the structure of how the bytes should be interpreted as this is used to get the robot information from the Universal Robots UR-10.

Answer (score 0):

`for item in data2:
   if item == "whatever":
        data2.pop(item)`

P.S I am using my phone, the code may not be indented properly.