# Why isn’t the byte printing a list showing the exact same hexadecimal number for each number in the list?

Tags: arrays, list, hex, byte, ascii

num = [27,68,188,9]

b1 = bytes(num)

print(b1)

Output:
b'\x1bD\xbc\t'

How does a t correspond to 9? Can’t get my head around this.Please help

Comment: I think this answer is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862497/python-bytes-literal-has-extra-characters-that-arent-hex-but-alter-the-value-o