# Python3 print in hex representation

Tags: python, hex

I can find lot's of threads that tell me how to convert values to and from hex. I do not want to convert anything. Rather I want to print the bytes I already have in hex representation, e.g.

```
byteval = '\x60'.encode('ASCII')
print(byteval)  # b'\x60'
```

Instead when I do this I get:

```
byteval = '\x60'.encode('ASCII')
print(byteval)  # b'`'
```

Because ` is the ASCII character that my byte corresponds to.

To clarify: type(byteval) is bytes, not string.

Comment: Is this work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340319/python-3-1-1-string-to-hex/2340358#2340358?

Comment: If you want `\x60` to appear, then you *want to* convert your string.

Comment: you could try `print(hex(ord(byteval)))`

Comment: My input is of type Bytes(), not a string, hence I do not want to convert it. the encoding of '\x60' using ASCII is to have a self contained example.

Comment: I don't understand why does it matter to you if its printed "\x60" or "`" ? in both cases doing ord(byteval) will return 96

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> print("b'" + ''.join('\\x{:02x}'.format(x) for x in byteval) + "'")
b'\x60'
```

Answer (score 1):

See this:

```
hexify = lambda s: [hex(ord(i)) for i in list(str(s))]
```

And

```
print(hexify("abcde"))
# ['0x61', '0x62', '0x63', '0x64', '0x65']
```

Another example:

```
byteval='\x60'.encode('ASCII')
hexify = lambda s: [hex(ord(i)) for i in list(str(s))]
print(hexify(byteval))
# ['0x62', '0x27', '0x60', '0x27']
```

Taken from https://helloacm.com/one-line-python-lambda-function-to-hexify-a-string-data-converting-ascii-code-to-hexadecimal/