# How do I decode radar data read by Python/socket like b'\x08\x00\x00\x00' to numbers

Tags: python, arrays, string, hex

I'm developing a Python3 program to process data from radar. In general, radar send data(hex numbers) to a port of my computer and I use socket to listen that port. And use code below to recive 4 bytes of data.

```
data = connection.recv(4)
print(data)
```

When testing my programm, radar send `08 00 00 01` and program print `b'\x08\x00\x00\x01'`. I understand the '\x' means that the next to characters is a hex number, but I want to get numbers like `[08, 00, 00, 01]` or a normal string from it. Tried the most obvious way:

```
strData = data.decode()
print(strData.split('\x'))
```

Failed with `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape`.

And situation goes worse if radar send `08 0D 00 00`, `print(data)` will print `b'\x08\r\x00\x00'`, which makes me realized that string operations can not handle this problem.

So, what is the right way to convert bytes like `b'\x08\x00\x00\x01'` to numbers like `08 00 00 01`.

String encoding drives me carzy -.- Although I am using Python3, solutions in Python2.7 is OK as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want integers ``8, ...``, 2-character hex strings ``"08", ...``, or just the entire number, i.e. ``134217729``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific case - you have a string of bytes, and you want to convert each byte to its integer equivalent - you can convert the bytestring directly to a list.

```
>>> bs = b'\x08\x00\x00\x01'
>>> ints = list(bs)
>>> ints
[8, 0, 0, 1]
```

This works because

> bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integer

so

> [For] a bytes object b, b[0] will be an integer, while b[0:1] will be a bytes object of length 1. (This contrasts with text strings, where both indexing and slicing will produce a string of length 1)

(Quotations from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview) for the `bytes` type).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already get the binary data. If you really want the hex-representation as a string, this [Answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340358/11468973) could help you.

If you would like to interpreted the data as for example a float, struct could be used

```
import struct
x = struct.unpack('f',data)
```